# Is there a way to consider a variable only in certain branches in rpart?

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

I'm trying to estimate a decision tree in R with the 'rpart' package. The unit of analysis are individuals, and two of the relevant variables are occupation (OCC=1 if working and OCC=0 if unemployed) and distance to the workplace (WORKD). WORKD only has values for people who do work (OCC=1) and is NA for people who do not work (if OCC=0, WORKD=NA).

The vectors for these variables would, then, look something like the following:

OCC <- c(1,0,0,1,1,0,1)

WORKD <- c(0.4,NA,NA,1.5,2.4,NA,0)

My question is: is there a way for rpart to consider the variable WORKD only in branches for which it has already partitioned OCC=1?

I wouldn't like to input WORKD=0 for unemployed individuals, as it would always consider WORKD as being more relevant than OCC. On the other hand, only using WORKD with this replacement would ignore that there are people working from their home (OCC=1, WORKD=0).